# Image is mixed on Collectionview when scrolling Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiimage, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collection view with image on the cell view. But when i'm scroll down the collection view, some of my image is mixed. I am not using any library to insert the image to UIImageView.

this is my code for reused the collection view cell.

```
cell.lvTitle.text = dataImage[indexPath.row]["nama"]
cell.delegate = self as! buttonClickedDelegate
cell.imageCode = dataImage[indexPath.row]["imageCode"]
cell.seq = dataImage[indexPath.row]["seq"]
cell.etcName = ""

if dataImage[indexPath.row]["tipe"] == "1" {
    let data = NSData(contentsOf: NSURL(string: dataImage[indexPath.row]["image"]!)! as URL)
    cell.imgFoto.image = UIImage(data: data! as Data)      
}

if dataImage[indexPath.row]["tipe"] == "0"{
    let data = Data(base64Encoded: dataImage[indexPath.row]["image"]!)
    cell.imgFoto.image = UIImage(data: data!)
}
```

Comment: have you given constraints to imageVIew in cell

Comment: Did you implement prepareForReuse in the cell

Comment: @qtngo thank you so much, i forgot to implement this method on view cell.

Answer (score 0):

as mention on [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54585813/image-is-mixed-on-collectionview-when-scrolling-swift-4) by [qtngo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6273012/qtngo).

i forgot to override prepareForReUse on view cell. thanks a lot